# How to add alternate css file in SharePoint 2013 Site

Tags: 2013, css

I am working on a applying custom css on a sharepoint team site. On the site i have SharePoint Server Publishing Infrstructure featured activated, but i dont see option where i can assign alternate CSS URL like we had on sharepoint 2010. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking in the Master Page link from Site Settings. I see Alternate CSS there.

Comment: Thanks go it, i had to reactivare sharepoint publishing feature in site features. That gave me access to page.